# Getting really weird entries in Apache log from Baidu.com?

Tags: apache, apache2, apache-log-files, baidu

I was looking through my server logs today, and I noticed this: (it's all one row)

```
118.244.179.250 - - [16/Oct/2013:20:59:25 +0000] "GET http://www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttphttp/www.baidu.comhttphttp/www.baidu.comhttp/www.baidu.com/ HTTP/1.1" 301 4605 "http://www.baidu.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)"
```

`"GET http://www.baidu.comhttphttphttphttphttp...`? Am I doing something wrong? Am I hosting someone else's website without knowing it? Is a guy named baidu trying to drive me crazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not doing anything wrong. I can asure you, that is not the baidu spider. The baidu spider would have a footprint like:

```
"GET /someurl HTTP/1.1" 200 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
```

The log indicates a HTTP spammer. A lookup on the given IP:

https://cleantalk.org/blacklists/118.244.179.250

Indicates a spammer. You can block the IP address or just ignore it, depending on the traffic he generates.